# TypeScript: How to specify types for function arguments when destructing arguments?

Tags: typescript

TS blows up with an error:

> Error:(8, 20) TS7031: Binding element 'on' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Error:(8, 24) TS7031: Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I have following function. I pass it two arguments.

```js
// 
function On({on, children}) {
  return (
    <div>{on} {children}</div>
  )
}
```

How do I specify types for arguments in such a case? This syntax does not work:

```js
function On({(on as boolean), (children as HTMLElement[])}) {
function On({(on: boolean), (children: HTMLElement[])}) {
function On({on: boolean, children: HTMLElement[]}) {
  return (
    <div>{on} {children}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The answers are correct; you need to do `{ on, children }: {on: boolean, children: HTMLElement[] }`.  There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) to allow type annotations inside binding patterns so if you want to see this you might want to go there and give it a .

Comment: As a side note, you don't pass it 2 arguments, you pass it 1 argument, that is an object with 2 properties

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
function On({on, children} : {on: boolean, children: HTMLElement[] }) {
    // your code
}
```

If you have a type/interface for the entire object you could also use that to make your code more readable:

```
interface OnOptions {
    on: boolean;
    children: HTMLElement[];
    someOtherProp: string;
}

function On({on, children} : OnOptions) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the section about [Function declarations](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#function-declarations)

```
type myType = { on: boolean, children: HTMLElement[]}
function On({on, children} : myType ) {
    // your code
}
```